# Using MultipleOutputs without context.write results empty files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I don't know how to use MultipleOutputs class. I'm using it to create multiple output files. Following is my Driver class's code snippet

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(CustomKeyValueTest.class);//class with mapper and reducer
    job.setOutputKeyClass(CustomKey.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(CustomKey.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(CustomValue.class);
    job.setMapperClass(CustomKeyValueTestMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(CustomKeyValueTestReducer.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    Path in = new Path(args[1]);
    Path out = new Path(args[2]);
    out.getFileSystem(conf).delete(out, true);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "islnd" , TextOutputFormat.class, CustomKey.class, Text.class);
    LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
    MultipleOutputs.setCountersEnabled(job, true);

    boolean status = job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

and in Reducer, I used MultipleOutputs like this,

```
private MultipleOutputs<CustomKey, Text> multipleOutputs;

@Override
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<>(context);
}

@Override
public void reduce(CustomKey key, Iterable<CustomValue> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ...
     multipleOutputs.write("islnd", key, pop, key.toString());
    //context.write(key, pop);

}

public void cleanup() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    multipleOutputs.close();
}
```

}

When I use context.write I get output files with data in it. But When I remove context.write the output files are empty. But I don't want to call context.write because it creates extra file part-r-00000. As Stated [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html)(last para in the description of class) I used LazyOutputFormat to avoid part-r-00000 file. But still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);

This means , in case you are not creating any output, dont create empty files.

```
Can you please look at hadoop counters and find 
 1. map.output.records
 2. reduce.input.groups
 3. reduce.input.records  to verify if your mappers are sending any data to mapper.
```

Code with IT for multioutput is 
http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/multipleoutputs-in-map-reduce/